# How to fixed second row in sorttable javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

Here is sorttable.js: https://kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/
and usage as below:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/sorttable.js"></script>
<table class="sortable" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Str</th>
        <th>Int</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

now I want to create a filter below first row:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/sorttable.js"></script>
<table class="sortable" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Str</th>
        <th>Int</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>filter
        <select>
        <option>a</option>
        <option>b</option>
        </select>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

but it will sorted, how can I edit this [sorttable.js](https://kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/sorttable.js) and can fixed the second row?
(my sorttable.js is save in local file)
very thaks!

Comment: While using a filter on the first column, do you still need it sorted? ...and what is the actual use of the filter?

Comment: @UdoE. If filter on the first column, it will not sorted,I want to put filter in second row is because of the neat viewing.
and that my filter is just a sample ,not actual use.

Comment: You should be explicit and specific about the role of the 'filter' and seperate its role from the sort function of sorttable. For instance, "filter is used to show only rows associated with the selected filter and hide other unrelated rows". This is a more explicit and clear specification.

Answer (score 0):

in`<table class="sortable">` 
you just need to remove `class="sortable"` and sortable.js won't work in the second row

Comment: so you want to keep sorttable, but you don't want sort filter?

Comment: I want to keep sorttable, and fixed the filter without sort

Comment: you can remove the filter Html part from the table.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this work, remove filter part into `<thead>`

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/sorttable.js"></script>
    <table class="sortable" border="1">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Person</th>
        <th>Monthly pay</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>filter
        <select>
        <option>a</option>
        <option>b</option>
        </select>
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr><td>Jan Molby</td><td>£12,000</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Steve Nicol</td><td>£8,500</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Steve McMahon</td><td>£9,200</td></tr>
    <tr><td>John Barnes</td><td>£15,300</td></tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr><td>TOTAL</td><td>£45,000</td></tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```